# String to character array returning different result in Visual Studio and Android Studio

Tags: java, c#, string, visual-studio, android-studio

The string that I want to convert into character array is ষ্টোর it is in Unicode and a Bengali word.

The problem is when I am converting it in **Visual studio** then it is returning **6 characters** but when I am converting it in **Android Studio** then it is showing **5 characters**.

In VS I am using **char[] arrayOfChars = someString.ToCharArray();** and in 
Android Studio **char[] arrayOfChars = someString.toCharArray();**

### [image: Visual Studio Debugging info]

### [image: Android Studio Debugging info]

N:B: My Android Studio IDE and Project Encoding is UTF-8. I am expecting same result as Visual Studio in Android Studio.

Comment: Are  you using different runtimes?

Comment: @minus I am not sure about runtimes. I am just compiling it in VS and in app studio and getting 2 different result. If you want to talk about Operating system then I am running App studio in Linux Mint and VS in Windows 10.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Java in Android Studio IDE and C# in Visual Studio. You need to make that clearer. If you look at this chart http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/bengalichart.html you can see that these characters are diacritics which are applied to another letter. 2507 contains the same two diacritics that 2503 and 2494 represent so that 2507 is more efficient but is basically the same thing. Both are conversions from UTF-16, so maybe they just convert to UTF-8 differently.

Comment: I'm truly fascinated by this question and all the answers which shows how deep is a seemingly trivial question of matching a symbol with a byte representation. I knew all this (in theory), but I never had a chance of seeing it in practice. It's like going to a museum to see a painting after having seen it only in pictures. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those two arrays are [unicode equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence), but are being represented by different normalization forms.  What seems to be happening is that the Java `ToCharArray` (or string representation) is using one normalization form, while the C# `ToCharArray` (or string representation) is using another.

[This page](http://unicode.org/charts/normalization/) contains a chart of different normalization forms for Bengali text - the fourth row there describes exactly what you're seeing:

[image: Bengali table]

I am only learning about this now, but it seems to me that the motivation for this is so that unicode implementations could remain compatible with pre-existing encodings wherever possible and practical.

For example, one pre-existing encoding may have used a single unicode character, while another pre-existing encoding may have instead used two characters combined. The solution settled on by the unicode folks is thus to support both, at the cost of not having a single "canonical" representation, as you've encountered here.

If you wish for your Java array to be normalized under the "D" normalization form that your C# array seems to be using, it appears that [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html) provides such a function. You may be looking for something like:

`someString = Normalizer.normalize(someString, Normalizer.Form.NFD);`

[Unicode standard annex 15](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) is the official document that describes these normalization forms.

Comment: Normalizer.normalize(someString, Normalizer.Form.NFD); Line was the answer :). thanks for putting your afford :)

Comment: More precisely, Unicode intends to be "round-trip-compatible", which means that encoding into and out of Unicode should produce the exact same bit pattern as transcoding directly. (Or, in the case of the same encoding, doing nothing at all.)

Answer (score 10):

You must have entered the string differently.

The text `ষ্টোর` is Unicode code points `09B7 09CD 099F 09CB 09B0`, i.e. `2487 2509 2463 2507 2480`, as your C# shows.

The values shown by Java, i.e. `2487 2509 2463 2503 2494 2480`, has the 4th character `2507` / `09CB` as the two characters `2503 2494` / `09C7 09BE`.

Looking them up, they are:

ো ↔ ['BENGALI VOWEL SIGN O' (U+09CB)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/09cb/index.htm)

vs.

ে ↔ ['BENGALI VOWEL SIGN E' (U+09C7)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/09c7/index.htm)
া ↔ ['BENGALI VOWEL SIGN AA' (U+09BE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/09be/index.htm)

which combined comes out to the same thing:

ষ্টোর ↔ `09B7 09CD 099F 09CB 09B0`
ষ্টোর ↔ `09B7 09CD 099F 09C7 09BE 09B0`

They are [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), and there are different ways to combine characters to get the same result.

Comment: Wow lot of information. Thanks Andreas. But I want to treat this string like the same way VS treat it in android studio :). I think then this will be solved. But I don't know how. But again thanks a lot :)

Comment: @bluetoothfx Solving depends on where text comes from. You're only showing the result, but the source of the text is likely where the problem is. Unless you explicitly ask to change canonical representation, Java (and I guess C#) will simple retain whatever representation they are given.

Comment: I am taking ("ষ্টোর") string just like that. Same source but different IDE. app studio running on linux mint, vs on win10.

Comment: @bluetoothfx Did you copy/paste the exact same string into both, or did you type it? Because, if I copy/paste the text into UTF-8 encoded Java source file, **I get length of 5. See [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/GFvj3G) for proof**. Java does not re-normalize the text by itself.